# iOS17&iPhone14Pro push to a viewcontroller but navigationBar frame error after screen rotate to landscapeRight and recover to portrait

Tags: iphone, ios17

my iPhone14Pro updated to iOS17.0, when I rotate screen to LandscapeRight to play video fullscreen, then I exited Fullscreen back to normal Portrait Mode. the navigationBar of UINavigationController's frame error

[image]

[image]